# rsync - specify negative exclusion (not inclusion)

Tags: rsync, backintime

I'm trying to tell rsync to ONLY include `.org` (or better yet, `.org` AND `.py` files). However, I have to do this through the `--exclude=` option, not the `--include=` option.

Reason: I'm using BackInTime and want to make a backup config that only include Org and Py files. That interface lets me specify *exclusion* options, but not *inclusion* options.

Is there a way to exclude everything but one (or two) specific extensions?

Comment: Germar says, in reply to [your issue #929 on GitHub](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime/issues/929), to craft a regular expression as an exclusion pattern. However, it is unclear whether BIT actually supports regular expressions in exclude patterns since the examples [in the documentation](https://backintime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#exclude) use filename globbing patterns, and the other `man` manuals are not clear on this.

Comment: I don't think it is a question of BIT supporting it, but rsync supporting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BackInTime has an option to pass any parameters to `rsync` that you want. In this case you could use `--include` and `--exclude` directly (or even `--filter`).

See the [Expert Options pane](https://backintime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#expert-options), last option.

Comment: It's still not trivial to craft the correct combination of options to `rsync`...

Comment: Thank you for this hint! But I don't think it solves the issue. I can craft a valid rsync command that works: `rsync -r --include="*/" --include="*.org" --include="*.py" --exclude="~/tmp/BACKUP" --exclude="*" --prune-empty-dirs  ~/tmp ~/tmp/BACKUP` However, passing even part of this to `rsync` via the BIT UI doesn't work. When using `ps` to examine the `rsync` command BIT generate, it is passing so many other options to `rsync` (and options are order-dependent) that it does not work.

Comment: Actually, the `filter` rule works! Or almost. When I add this to Expert Options `--filter="+ *.org" --filter="+ *.py" --filter="- *.*" --prune-empty-dirs` then it works well enough. It includes files WITHOUT extensions also (because the exclude filter is `*.*`). If I make the exclude filter `*`, then everything is excluded.

Comment: This works: `--filter="+ *.py" --filter="+ *.org" --filter="-! */" --prune-empty-dirs`

Comment: @Kusalanander I'd say that's true for any moderately complex combination of filter rules, and not particularly something specific to BIT.